# HLOOKUP-VBA in loop for specified Range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to do lookup in a specified range(rows X to AF in "main" tab[Sheet1]) which I am doing using VBA `hlookup` function. The problem I am facing is that I am not able to do this lookup in a loop, which means once the `hlookup` is done in `X2:AF2`, then it should do the calculation in X3:AF3 for next row.

I need to do this because the Tablehandle[sheeet2] result will change every time (macro will clear this sheet) and the headers will not in order.

So can someone help me to get `hlookup` in a loop for a specified row?

My "Main" sheet
[image]

"TableHandle" sheet
[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub hlookup1()

Dim i, r As Long
For i = 1 To Range("K100000").End(xlUp).Row - 1

'first macro will get the table inside sheet ...

Sheets("TableHandle").Select
    'Range("A2").Select
    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    'Range("A2:B10").Select
    'Selection.Copy
    Range("F1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True

'hlookup
    Sheets("Main").Select
    Range("X2").Select
    Range("X" & i + 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=HLOOKUP(R1C,TableHandle!R1C6:R2C14,2,0)"
    Selection.Copy
    Range("X2:AF2").Select  'PROBLEM from Here, it will again calculate in x2 to af2 range)
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
            Cells.Replace What:="#N/A", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    i = i + 1
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours is a good idea but in practice it has a number of drawbacks as demonstrated by the error handling you had planned. I think you would also have to replace the formulas you insert with so much effort with the values they produce. Please try this code instead. It transfers data from the *TableHandler* sheet to the *Main* without the use of worksheet formulas.

```
Sub hlookup1()
    ' 211

    Dim Data        As Variant                  ' source data
    Dim Headers     As Range                    ' column captions in 'Main'
    Dim Fnd         As Range                    ' Find the column caption
    Dim Rs          As Long                     ' Row: Source (= 'Data')
    Dim Cs          As Long                     ' Column: Source
    Dim Rt          As Long                     ' Row: Target
    Dim Ct          As Long                     ' Column: Target
    
    'first macro will get the table inside sheet ...
    With Worksheets("TableHandle")              ' data source
        Rs = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Data = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rs, "X")).Value
        ' Row 1 of 'Data' holds the column headers because
        ' SheetRow(2) became the ArrayRow(1)
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False          ' speed up execution
    With Worksheets("Main")
        Set Headers = .Range("A2:X2")
        
        ' start in array row 2 because array row 1 holds the column captions
        For Rs = 2 To UBound(Data)              ' loop through all rows
            Rt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            For Cs = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)       ' loop through the columns of each row
                Set Fnd = Headers.Find(Data(1, Cs), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then      ' skip column not found
                    .Cells(Rt, Fnd.Column).Value = Data(Rs, Cs)
                End If
            Next Cs
        Next Rs
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If a column in the *TableHandler* should not be found the macro will not transfer data, leaving the target column blank. If you want a warning it would have to be added. There is a little confusion in your question as to rows and columns. Should I have guessed wrongly here or there I trust you will be able to make the required modifications. However, you are welcome to ask for help, too.

Comment: Thanks Friend, i used this code and modified for myself. i answered my question with correct code.

Answer (score 0):

it was important and i spent all day to make this possible, i ans my question here.

the code is shortned as below, it works fast and efficient. thanks for suggestions!

```
    Dim Hlookp As Variant
    Hlookp = Application.HLookup(Range("B1:J1").Value, Sheets("TableHandle").Range("F1:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row), 2, False)
    Range("B" & i + 1 & ":J" & i + 1).Value = Hlookp
```